# How does one merge texts together? like a version control system would?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version-control, merge, text-manipulation

Wikipedia says this is pretty good: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)#Three-way_merge

But how does one implement that? or are there any gems / plugins for Ruby on Rails that will handle that for me?

My situation:
• I have base text
• changes from person A
• changes from person B
• both changes should be included and not overriding the other

any directions I could be pointed in? thanks!

Comment: have you try Google ? first result [is](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/merge3)

Comment: A google search for "ruby gem three way merge" has [this link](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/merge3) as the top hit.  I have not used it, but it "sounds" like a possibility.

Comment: I am not good at google today o.o

Comment: actually.... I think it'l broken: Merge3::three_way("1234567890", "1a23456", "1234b56", false)
RuntimeError: Error nil string passed start=-12 length=22 str=-=

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at the [merge3](http://rubygems.org/gems/merge3) gem again [[source]](https://github.com/dancinglightning/merge3).

This small example explains it:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'merge3'

start = <<TEXT
This is the baseline.
The start.
The end.
TEXT
changed_A = <<TEXT
This is the baseline.
The start (changed by A).
The end.
TEXT
changed_B = <<TEXT
This is the baseline.
The start.
B added this line.
The end.
TEXT

result = Merge3::three_way(start, changed_A, changed_B)

puts result
```

The output it generates is:

```
This is the baseline.
The start (changed by A).
B added this line.
The end.
```

I am not sure how it handles merge conflicts, and since it is supposed to handle 3-way merges of files, it seems to be line-based. If that is a problem (as your example tries to compare simple string), you could add a newline between every character.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing versioned text that you want to be able to merge, then it sounds like you have a perfect use case for calling a version control system. Store the text in files and call the VCS for version control operations (perhaps the Git or Grit gems would be helpful).

Comment: I am forever a noob when it comes to versioning like git.  I know you can make diffs with the git gem. http://rubydoc.info/gems/git/1.2.5/ . But there are no examples of usage / how to do things. o.o

Comment: Yeah, me too. Now I understand. Perhaps there are usage examples somewhere? Or try Grit?

Comment: grit looks like it functions exactly like git. Is there a way to just merge files (though blocks of text would be better) without a repository?

Comment: Not AFAIK, but if you have more than a file or two, you should have a repository anyway, no?

Comment: Well, I'm doing versioning for a document, so... it's just a bunch of variations on one "file"

Comment: Just one document, or is the system designed to support more?

Comment: It'll end up being many documents per account. So.. I guess using a versioning system might work. It kinda would act as a second database... not sure how I feel about that though. I don't think our server does hourly backups of the HD. hmmmmm. this is tricky.

Comment: I tend to think it's better to farm out to Git than reinvent the wheel, but if you really need the DB backups, I can see why you might not do that.